# Select only digits from Text

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

Anyone can help how can I select only digits from Text?

Strings can be random like:

```
ABCD123DEF -> Result must be 123
393SEA981F -> Result must be 393981
```

Thanks!Firebird version is 2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first that comes to my mind:

use stored procedure as:

```
SET TERM ^ ;

create or alter procedure GET_DIGIT_ONLY (
    IPARAM varchar(32))
returns (
    OPARAM varchar(32))
as
declare variable I integer;
begin
  oparam = '';
  i = 1;
  while (i <= char_length(:iparam)) do
  begin
    if (substring(:iparam from i for 1) similar to '[0123456789]')  then
      oparam = :oparam || (substring(:iparam from i for 1));
    i = :i + 1;
  end
  suspend;
end^

SET TERM ; ^
```

How to use:

```
execute procedure get_digit_only :input_param
returning_values :output_param
```

or

```
select get_digit_only.oparam from get_digit_only ('393SEA981F')
```

Comment: In Firebird 3 you could make a function instead (would be similar).

Answer (score 2):

You could make EXECUTE BLOCK

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
RETURNS (number VARCHAR(20))
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE temp VARCHAR(20);
  DECLARE VARIABLE temp_char VARCHAR(1);
  DECLARE VARIABLE step INT;
BEGIN
  FOR SELECT
    sometable.sometext
  FROM sometable
  INTO :temp DO
  BEGIN
    step = 1;
    number = '';
    WHILE (:step < CHAR_LENGTH(:temp)) DO
    BEGIN
      temp_char = SUBSTRING(:temp FROM step FOR 1);
      IF (POSITION(:temp_char IN '0123456789') > 0) THEN
        number = :number || :temp_char;

      step = step + 1;
    END
    SUSPEND;
  END
END
```

OR stored procedure by replacing `EXECUTE BLOCK` with `CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SomeProcedure`.

EXECUTE BLOCK is runnable as it is, STORED PROCEDURE require a call like

```
SELECT SomeProcedure.number
FROM SomeProcedure
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dirty data source this (Firebird 3.0) function may be of help.

- Thanks to [Val Marinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4764244/val-marinov) for the original function.

```sql
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION GET_DIGIT_ONLY (IPARAM VARCHAR(15))
RETURNS INTEGER
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE I INTEGER;
DECLARE VARIABLE ONUM INTEGER;
DECLARE VARIABLE OPARAM VARCHAR(15);
DECLARE VARIABLE V_WORK VARCHAR(15);
BEGIN
    OPARAM = '';
    ONUM = 0;
    I = 1;
    V_WORK = TRIM(IPARAM);
    IF(V_WORK IS NULL) THEN
    BEGIN
        RETURN 0;
    END
    IF(TRIM(V_WORK) = '') THEN
    BEGIN
        RETURN 0;
    END
    WHILE (I <= CHAR_LENGTH(:V_WORK)) DO
    BEGIN
        IF (SUBSTRING(:V_WORK FROM I FOR 1) SIMILAR TO '[0123456789]')  THEN
            OPARAM = :OPARAM || (SUBSTRING(:V_WORK FROM I FOR 1));
        I = :I + 1;
    END
    IF(TRIM(:OPARAM) = '') THEN
    BEGIN
        RETURN 0;
    END
    ONUM = CAST(:OPARAM AS INTEGER);
    RETURN ONUM;
END;

SET TERM ; ^
;
```

Following the same idea here is a function to extract alpha characters only:

```sql
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION GET_ALPHA_ONLY (IPARAM VARCHAR(15))
RETURNS VARCHAR(15)
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE I INTEGER;
DECLARE VARIABLE OPARAM VARCHAR(15);
DECLARE VARIABLE V_WORK VARCHAR(15);
BEGIN
    OPARAM = '';
    I = 1;
    V_WORK = TRIM(IPARAM);
    IF(V_WORK IS NULL) THEN
        BEGIN
        RETURN '@';
    END
    IF(TRIM(V_WORK) = '') THEN
    BEGIN
        RETURN '@';
    END
    WHILE (I <= CHAR_LENGTH(:V_WORK)) DO
    BEGIN
        IF (SUBSTRING(:V_WORK FROM I FOR 1) SIMILAR TO '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]')  THEN
            OPARAM = :OPARAM || (SUBSTRING(:V_WORK FROM I FOR 1));
        I = :I + 1;
    END
    IF(TRIM(:OPARAM) = '') THEN
    BEGIN
        RETURN '@';
    END
    RETURN OPARAM;
END;

SET TERM ; ^
;
```